Multi-insert statement in INSERT command
I have to download the data residing in a SQLite database in my Xamarin app into a Firebird database which is on my PC on the same WiFi network and I reach with IP address. Everything works correctly, but the unloading times are very long.
This is the connection string:
connessione = @"Server=" + ip_server + @";User=sysdba;Password=XXXXXXXX;Pooling=true;Database=" + ip_server + @":C:\\FirebirdSQL\\Photo.FDB";

This is the SQL statement:
string _dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), VarGlobal.dbSQLITE);
var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
FbCommand cmdfb = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO photo (id,rifiddir,immaginebit) VALUES (@id,@rifiddir,@immaginebit)", conn);      
cmdfb.Parameters.Add("@id", FbDbType.VarChar);
cmdfb.Parameters.Add("@rifiddir", FbDbType.VarChar);
cmdfb.Parameters.Add("@immaginebit", FbDbType.Binary);
conn.Open();
var tuttelefoto = db.Query<Photo>("SELECT id,rifiddir,immaginebit FROM Photo");
foreach (var singolafoto in tuttelefoto)
{
    cmdfb.Parameters["@id"].Value = singolafoto.Id;
    cmdfb.Parameters["@rifiddir"].Value = singolafoto.rifiddir;
    cmdfb.Parameters["@immaginebit"].Value = singolafoto.immaginebit;
    await cmdfb.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); 
}

conn.Close();

It all works, but it takes 10 seconds for each insert. I wanted to rewrite the code in just one line:
FbCommand cmdfb = new FbCommand(" INSERT INTO PHOTO " +
" SELECT '1', 'one' FROM RDB$DATABASE " +    " UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'two ' FROM RDB$DATABASE " +    " UNION ALL SELECT '3', 'three' FROM RDB$DATABASE " +    " UNION ALL SELECT '4', 'four' FROM RDB$DATABASE ", conn);

The photo size is max 1,5 Mb. The WiFi is 166 Mbps.
How can I insert a byte[] field in text format? Could this solve my problems? Many of you will tell me not to connect directly to the database, but to use a web service. I know. But the app only works when the phone and PC are on the same network.

Although you can insert binary data using a binary-string literal, those are restricted to 64KB. That said, I don't see why this statement would take 10 seconds per insert. I don't regular program C#, but maybe you should be using the batch facility of FbBatchCommand, assuming you use Firebird 4 or higher.

See The Firebird FAQ. How to export data from database and import into another?

@i486 They are selecting all photos from the SQLite database, iterating over the result set, and then inserting them one by one into the Firebird database. They are not reselecting the photos after each insert.

It is good to try the same without async method (cmdfb.ExecuteNonQuery()). Also estimate the time for reading of 1 photo and try with 500KB (150KB) images - to see whether time will be 3 (10) times shorter or similar.

I did some downloads today with the same code
The WiFi is 100 Mbps.
size 100%  3456x4608    1,7 MB   8sec/first download   7,5 sec/photo
size 50%   1725x2300    432 kb   6sec/first download   6,5 sec/photo
size 20%   750x1000     104 kb   1sec/first download    1,5 sec/photo
The measurements are based on downloads of 6 photos for each test.
In the 4th column the latency times before starting the first download are recorded
Can anyone tell me if these are compliant insertion times?

It sounds very slow to me, but is the download done from the SQLite or the Firebird database in those tests?

I read from the sqlite database on the phone and download to the fiewbirdsql database on the PC

@L.Andrea As a matter of terminology, that is uploading, not downloading. In any case, you could try changing the PacketSize connection property (max value is 32767, default is 8192), as it also seems to be used for transferring blobs in the Firebird ADO.net provider.

@MarkRotteveel When program is running on the PC where results are stored, it is downloading from phone. If program was executed on the phone, then it is uploading.

@i486 In the case it is running on the PC, the program is downloading from the phone and uploading to the Firebird database server. If the program is running on the phone, it is uploading to the Firebird database.

Mark you are magnificent. I changed the package size to 32767 and the upload speed doubled. Now for a max resolution of 2592x3456 and it takes 4 seconds but I can accept even lower resolutions. Your solution worked. I thank you infinitely. I hope the solution can help someone else. HI

Part of the problem is how blobs are transferred between the client and Firebird, and the default transfer size used by the Firebird ADO.net provider (FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient).
In Firebird, blobs are sent out of band. That is, their data is not transmitted inline in an execute, but it needs to be sent separately by the driver1. First, the driver needs to create a blob, and then send the data in blocks (a.k.a. segments) in a request/response style. This request/response style introduces additional latency2.
In the case of the Firebird ADO.net provider, the segment size used to transfer blobs defaults to 8192 bytes (8 KiB), and can be controlled by the PacketSize connection property (with a maximum of 32767 bytes, or 32 KiB - 1).
For example, with a photo of 1.5 MiB, the default value of PacketSize (8192) means the photo is transferred in 192 packets. If you use the maximum of 32767, you transfer it in 49 packets. Say the roundtrip latency between the client and server is 10 milliseconds, then that is the difference between 1.9 seconds and 0.5 seconds (this ignores things like the time it takes for the data itself to be read and transferred, and the time the Firebird database might spend on storing the data).
TL;DR: Set the PacketSize connection property to 32767.


Since Firebird 4.0 this can be partially addressed with batch execution, but a lot of driver don't support this yet (fully) because it makes execution a lot more complex
Drivers can address this by sending multiple requests before reading the response from the network, but not all drivers do

